Mathematical modelling of disease networks
I am working on a problem involving mathematical modelling of a closed population using graph networks.

In this problem, people start of healthy - from there,

they can either $\tt recover$,
stay $\tt sick$
or $\tt die$.
If they get $\tt better$, they can fall $\tt sick$ again or still $\tt die$.



In the problem I am working on:
Let $G = (V, E)$ be an undirected graph where:

$V$ is the set of vertices (nodes)
with $|V| = n = 100$ (total number of nodes)
$E$ is the set of edges

In this graph, any person at time $t$, depending on the the health status of their neighbors (i.e. neighbors can infect a person), their state vector at time $t$ as:
$$ S(t) = \begin{bmatrix} S_{\text{HNI}}(t) \\ S_{\text{CI}}(t) \\ S_{\text{HPI}}(t) \\ S_{\text{D}}(t) \end{bmatrix} $$
Where

HNI = Healthy (Never Infected)
CI = Currently Infected
HPI = Healthy (Previously Infected)
D = Dead.

The transition matrix $P$ represents the probabilities of moving from one state to another (I am not sure if this description is fully accurate since the probability of infection depends on how many infected neighbors a perosn has):
$$ P = \begin{bmatrix} 
p_{\text{HNI,HNI}} & p_{\text{HNI,CI}} & p_{\text{HNI,HPI}} & p_{\text{HNI,D}} \\
p_{\text{CI,HNI}} & p_{\text{CI,CI}} & p_{\text{CI,HPI}} & p_{\text{CI,D}} \\
p_{\text{HPI,HNI}} & p_{\text{HPI,CI}} & p_{\text{HPI,HPI}} & p_{\text{HPI,D}} \\
p_{\text{D,HNI}} & p_{\text{D,CI}} & p_{\text{D,HPI}} & p_{\text{D,D}}
\end{bmatrix} $$
$$ P = \begin{bmatrix} 
0.69 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.01 \\
0 & 0.87 & 0.1 & 0.03 \\
0 & 0.3 & 0.68 & 0.02 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$
I simulated this network using a computer (using R):

I understand this problem is similar to a SIR problem, but I was wondering if the following questions could be answered:

How long on average will it take for the whole population to be infected at least once ?.
On the $50$th day of the simulation, what percent of the population will be currently infected ?.
At some point, will the entire population be dead ?.

These questions sound difficult and I am not sure if they have closed form solutions.
Thus, I tried to repeat the simulations to help me answer these kinds of questions:

I would repeat the simulation many times and take the average answer to each of these questions.
But I was just wondering - do these questions have analytical solutions or do they have to be numerically simulated?

PS $1$: I am aware that in some situations with rare events probabilities ( e.g. rare disease transmission ), I would need to run each simulation for many iterations to observe even one event - and then repeat this again and again, thus making simulation infeasible for such situations. In such situations, I think closed form solutions would be better.
PS $2$: Does anyone want the R code that I used in this problem ?. I can provide it if someone wants.


You might look at the terminal probabilities. See Perron eigenvector.

thank you rural reader! I will check it out!

The transition matrix $P$ is for every vertice $v \in V$? Why does it not depend on the neighbors of $v$?

thank you for your comment @NN2 : It does ... I just didn't know how to write it in that format...

The current transition matrix is then not correct. You could describe the relationship between $v$ and its neighbors (for example: if 50% of the neighbors is infected, then $v$ is infected,....). After that, perhaps someone (not sure it's me) can help you to write a more correct transition matrix $P$.

I suppose that you have also what I will call the 'map' of all peoples (list of neighbors for every one). In your pictures, it seems that the map is always the same (normal), but you rotate the picture for some reason. Do you confirm. Normally, rows 1 and 3 of you matrix are highly dependant of number of neighbors that are infected.

This is NOT an answer. Just some long comments in the spirit of "how to start working on these types of questions"... Note: I am an engineer, not a mathematician or population biologist. I have no background in modeling these type of problems and simply presenting a few things that came to my mind when I read the question (i.e. to list things that I would like to consider if I had the right mathematical skills to deal with them).

You graph shows some connections among neighbors. It is not immediately clear to me what the basis for the graph connections is. One may define a ROI (radius of infection), if one were to uniformly distribute the population on a large symmetric shape, such that ignoring the periphery, for a large population, the number of neighbors for any individual is roughly the same. The radius could be just the nearest set of equidistant neighbors one is connected to, to simplify. I imagine starting with a healthy population in this model and randomly replace one (or $n$) healthy individuals with infected individuals and see how the disease spreads.

I do not see a distinction between HNI and HPI wither in terms of them counting towards being sick or contirbuting towards further sickness in the population.

Sick individuals should tend to get healthy unless reinfected within a specified time (if they become reinfected within the specified time, their sickness should accumulate). There should be a rate of propagation of sickness (assume radially equal in all directions). This may or may not depend on how sick the individual is. There has to be some sense of sickness threshold, beyond which an accumulated sickness results in death.

Dead individuals can be considered not to propagate sickness anymore.

Rate of recovering vs rate of propagation matters for spreading. This is where the proabilities of transmission to a neighbor will come into picture besides the transmission vs recovering rates.


Though I don't have the skills to analytically deal with these parameters, I can imagine it being possible depending upon the simplifications one does for each of these factors. I hope at least one of the points helps you in a better numeric modeling at least.
